# Accessing variable inside array of objects JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to access "photor" and "captionr" of each object stored in that JSON array. But it doesn't work and gives me an error "Cannot read property 'photor' of undefined"

```
var slideshow = {

    directory: "images/",

    photos:[
            { "photor": "aurelius.jpg", "captionr" : "Mark Aurelius"}, 
            { "photor": "cesar.png", "captionr" : "Gaius Julius Ceasar"},
            { "photor": "couple.jpg", "captionr" : "Greek Couple"},
            { "photor": "flavian.jpg", "captionr" : "Flavian Woman"},
            { "photor": "lucius.jpg", "captionr" : "Lucius Verus"},
            { "photor": "lupe.jpg", "captionr" : "Emperor Caracalla"},
            { "photor": "sabina.jpg", "captionr" : "Sabina"}
            ],

    currentPhoto: 0,

    getPrevious: function(){
            if (this.currentPhoto == 0) 
                this.currentPhoto = this.photos.length-1;
            else
                this.currentPhoto--;

            var photo   = this.directory + this.photos[this.currentPhoto][0].photor;
            var caption = this.photos[this.currentPhoto][1].captionr;
            return { "photo": photo, "caption": caption };
        };

         var photo=this.directory+this.photos[this.currentPhoto].photor;
    var caption=this.photos[this.currentPhoto].captionr;
```

Comment: Did you try var photo   = this.directory + this.photos[this.currentPhoto].photor; that is without [0]??

Comment: yes, it says "file not found" then, even though files are there

Comment: `var photo   = this.directory + this.photos[this.currentPhoto].photor;
            var caption = this.captions[this.currentPhoto].captionr;`

Comment: Can you send complete code in jsfiddle? Make sure 'this.currentPhoto' returns you index of current photo and try my code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8mgb3m1c/   it's strange as I have all those files in "images" folder and the one that I put in html works showing the first image, but it keep giving me "file not found" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`var photo   = this.directory + this.photos[this.currentPhoto].photor;`

Answer (score 0):

Probably , you are struggling with behaviour of **this** in JS

Try this -

```
getPrevious: function(){
            var ref=this;
            if (ref.currentPhoto == 0) 
                ref.currentPhoto = ref.photos.length-1;
            else
                ref.currentPhoto--;

            var photo   = ref.directory + ref.photos[ref.currentPhoto][0].photor;
            var caption = ref.captions[ref.currentPhoto][1].captionr;
            return { "photo": photo, "caption": caption };
        };
```